# How do I get Thunderbird to show the attachments expanded

Tags: thunderbird, attachments

The latest update to Thunderbird email client shows the attachments under a separate panel.  I'd like the panel to display expanded automatically.

How do I do that?  It doesn't seem to be in the help files or the release notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this writeup on the Attachment Pane Redesign](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_5.0_-_New_Features_and_Changes#Attachment_pane_redesign) on MozillaZine,
you can add the following to userChrome.css to remove the attachment toggles:

```
#attachmentView > [collapsed="true"] {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#attachmentToggle {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**Edit:** Corrected filename to userChrome.css

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using the "Attachment Options" extension referenced in the article.

Comment: Sanjay- nice call, I used the code in your answer however you should note, the file and directory probably need to be created and the file name is not userContent.css (that has a different purpose) it is userChrome.css.

Comment: Ahh .. good catch on the filename. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: PLEASE somebody update this for Thunderbird 10.0. 
I just spent 4 hours trying to figure this out, and google has failed me.

Answer (score 15):

Right-click on the attachment pane, and click "Initially Show Attachment Pane."

(The option was added in Thunderbird v24 and up.)

Comment: And it seems as if it this option was removed again. At least I can't find it in Thunderbird 38.7.0.

Comment: It's here in 45.8.0 and saved me when `userChrome.css` was ignored by TB

Comment: This worked for me in Betterbird v102

Answer (score 5):

This ability to change this through the UI has been removed in newer versions, but it still exists in about:config (Preferences > Advanced > General > Config Editor...)

Set `mailnews.attachments.display.start_expanded` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

In the version I have, 45.6.0, there is an option under the View tab to Display Attachments Inline that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has been asked over 11 years ago, I'm sharing a solution for recent versions of Thunderbird. In my case, I'm referring to Thunderbird 102.11.0.

1. From the main menu, go to `Tools` > `Settings`. Alternatively, click on the gear icon in the bottom-left corner.
2. Go to the `General` tab (you should be there already) and scroll down until reaching the `Config Editor` button.

[image]

3. At this point, filter for the attachment attributes and set the properties `mail.inline_attachments` and `mail.inline_attachments.text` to true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to
Preferences > Advanced > General > Config Editor...
and set
mail.inline_attachments -> true

If you'd like to show attachments pane when composing new email, then set
mail.compose.show_attachment_pane -> true